# Flatten a data frame with one parent and one child column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below data frame as input.

```
+--------+---------+
|   child|   parent|
+--------+---------+
|street_1|   city_1|
|street_2|   city_2|
|street_3|   city_1|
|street_4|   city_2|
|  city_2|  state_2|
|  city_1|  state_1|
| state_1|country_1|
| state_2|country_2|
+--------+---------+
```

and below should be the output

```
+---------+-------+------+--------+
|  country|  state|  city|  street|
+---------+-------+------+--------+
|country_1|state_1|city_1|street_3|
|country_1|state_1|city_1|street_1|
|country_2|state_2|city_2|street_4|
|country_2|state_2|city_2|street_2|
+---------+-------+------+--------+
```

I tried below approach. But it seems to be a overkill. Please suggest if there is a better approach.

```
d1.show()
+--------+---------+
|   child|   parent|
+--------+---------+
|street_1|   city_1|
|street_2|   city_2|
|street_3|   city_1|
|street_4|   city_2|
|  city_2|  state_2|
|  city_1|  state_1|
| state_1|country_1|
| state_2|country_2|
+--------+---------+

d2.show()
+--------+---------+
| child_2| parent_2|
+--------+---------+
|street_1|   city_1|
|street_2|   city_2|
|street_3|   city_1|
|street_4|   city_2|
|  city_2|  state_2|
|  city_1|  state_1|
| state_1|country_1|
| state_2|country_2|
+--------+---------+


df_with_state=d1.join(d2,d1['parent']==d2['child_2'],'left').where(d2['child_2'].isNull()).select(d1['parent'].alias('country'),d1['child'].alias('state'))

df_with_city=d1.join(df_with_state,df_with_state['state']==d1['parent'],'inner').select(*df_with_state.columns,d1['child'].alias('city'))

df_with_street=d1.join(df_with_city,df_with_city['city']==d1['parent'],'inner').select(*df_with_city.columns,d1['child'].alias('street'))

df_with_street.show()

+---------+-------+------+--------+
|  country|  state|  city|  street|
+---------+-------+------+--------+
|country_1|state_1|city_1|street_3|
|country_1|state_1|city_1|street_1|
|country_2|state_2|city_2|street_4|
|country_2|state_2|city_2|street_2|
+---------+-------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems reasonable to me. If you want more readability, you can follow this code:

```py
country_df = df.toDF('state', 'country')
state_df = df.toDF('city', 'state')
city_df = df.toDF('street', 'city')

final_df = country_df.join(state_df, on='state')
final_df = final_df.join(city_df, on='city')

final_df = final_df.select('country', 'state', 'city', 'street')
final_df.sort('country', 'state', 'city', 'street').show()
# +---------+-------+------+--------+
# |  country|  state|  city|  street|
# +---------+-------+------+--------+
# |country_1|state_1|city_1|street_1|
# |country_1|state_1|city_1|street_3|
# |country_2|state_2|city_2|street_2|
# |country_2|state_2|city_2|street_4|
# +---------+-------+------+--------+
```